# MYSQL nested query into Laravel Eloquent ORM

Tags: mysql, laravel

Hey Im trying to pass a simple nested query to Laravel ORM, so Im looking for help, I want to know what is the best approach to solve it.

**Student belong to a course, the course has many students, students can participate to many internships and every internship can have many students.**

This are the importants tables: Courses, Students(id,name,course_id), Internships and pivot_table_attendance(internship_id,student_id) and I need to know the total number of students per course in each internship

Here is the raw query that I have:

```
  SELECT count(*), internship_id FROM "attendance" where student_id in 
  (select id from "students" where course_id in 
  (select id from from "Courses"  where  name='X course')) 
  group by internship_id
```

Comment: Names of the tables are not enough, post the table structure. Ex: student => id, name, address... etc. specially foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined the relations in the Models, it should look something like this (not tested):

```
$result = Attandace::selectRaw('count(*), internship_id')
              ->whereHas('students.courses', function($query) {
                   $query->where('courses.name', 'X course');
              })->groupBy('internship_id');
```